# Octal Numbering System

Tags: octal

In octal, I'm typing the number 10.34 into a couple of different online converters to convert them to decimal, and they say that it's an invalid octal number.

I know that the octal number 10 can be worked out by

1x8^1 + 1x8^0 = 8

But is it possible to workout the right side of the radix.

Comment: Most octal converters will only work with integers. You can treat the right/decimal portion just like the left side, under the premise that the decimal can range from `[.0, .7777..]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy. Just continue the pattern from the left side of the dot:

```
1*8^1 + 0*8^0 + 3*8^-1 + 4*8^-2 = 8.4375
```